# 使用しない変数をインターフェース型で宣言する意味と、io.Discard に関する質問

Tags: go

`io.Discard` の [ソースコード](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/ioutil/ioutil.go#L122) を見ていて疑問点が２点あります。

**Q1.**

Goの基本的な文法に関する質問になってしまいますが、以下は何を意図しているのでしょうか。

```golang
// devNull implements ReaderFrom as an optimization so io.Copy to
// ioutil.Discard can avoid doing unnecessary work.
var _ io.ReaderFrom = devNull(0)
```

コード内のコメントから、`devNull` が `io.Copy` で使われる場合に備えて「`io.ReaderFrom`インタフェースを実装している」ことを宣言しているのだろうとは思うのですが、一体どういう理屈で上記がインタフェースを実装していることの宣言になるのでしょうか（そういう文法なのだと言われるとそれまでなのですが…）。

**Q2.**

以下のように `WriteString` 関数が定義されていますが、

```golang
func (devNull) WriteString(s string) (int, error) {
    return len(s), nil
}
```

そもそも `io.Discard` は `ioutil` パッケージに `io.Writer` 型の変数として宣言されているため、

```golang
// Discard is an io.Writer on which all Write calls succeed
// without doing anything.
var Discard io.Writer = devNull(0)
```

例えば以下のように呼び出すことはできません。

```golang
ioutil.Discard.WriteString("hoge")
// ビルドエラー：
// ioutil.Discard.WriteString undefined 
// (type io.Writer has no field or method WriteString)
```

一体なんのために存在しているのでしょうか。

Comment: Q1 については [What does an underscore and interface name after keyword var mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13194272/what-does-an-underscore-and-interface-name-after-keyword-var-mean) が参考になるかと思います。

Comment: Q2 については [io.WriteString()](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/io/io.go#L289) で呼び出されていますね。(`io.WriteString(ioutil.Discard, "hogehoge fugaguga")`)

Comment: @metropolis ２点とも理解できました。ありがとうございます。Q2はstringWriterインタフェースの存在を知らなかったため、まさか型アサーションして使われているとは思わず、使用されている箇所を見つけ出すことができませんでした。

Comment: 質問の内容をタイトルに反映しましたが、私は Q2 がよく理解できなかったので中途半端なタイトルになっています。どなたか、改善していただければと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己回答です。（metropolisさんのコメントより）

**A1.**

`devNull` が `io.ReaderFrom` インタフェースを実装していることを、コンパイル時にチェックさせることが目的。

型が `io.ReaderFrom` である何らかの変数を宣言して、それに `devNull` を代入することができるのであれば、`devNull` は `io.ReaderFrom` インタフェースを実装している、ということになる。また「なんらかの変数」は宣言後に使用しないので、ブランク識別子（アンダースコア）にしている。チェックするだけなので、この行を削除してもコンパイルできるし動作も変わらない。

**A2.**

同パッケージの `stringWriter` インタフェースの実装。
`stringWriter` インタフェースは、`io.WriteString` 関数や `io.multiWriter.WriteString` 関数の中で型アサーションがokであれば委譲される。

例えば以下の時、内部では `Discard` の `WriteString` 関数が使われる。

```golang
io.WriteString(ioutil.Discard, "hogehoge fugafuga")
```